# Отправка сообщения указанному человеку в Telegram через Python

Tags: python, парсер, telegram, sendmessage

хочу написать программу на Python для того, чтобы писать указываемому человеку указываемое сообщение. Возможна ли реализация подобного?

Comment: Думаю, да......

Comment: Вы хотя бы пытались искать что-то в интернете? PyTelegramBotAPI и aiogram вылезают по первым ссылкам в поисковике

Comment: Тут важно помнить, что бот первым писать не может

Answer (score 0):

да если писать конкретному человеку подойдёт библиотекаPyTelegramBotAPI вот пример кода

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я твой бот. Как я могу помочь?")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)
    bot.forward_message('USER_ID_HERE', message.chat.id, message.message_id)

bot.polling()
```

В этом примере бот пересылает все полученные от пользователя сообщения другому пользователю с идентификатором 'USER_ID_HERE'. Пожалуйста, замените 'USER_ID_HERE' на идентификатор пользователя, которому вы хотите пересылать сообщения.

Обратите внимание, что идентификатор пользователя в Telegram - это число, которое можно получить, например, через специальные боты или при помощи API Telegram.